# make a navbar with a dropdown that instead of showing the link vertical, show them horizontal

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi everyone i'm trying to replicate this style of navbar https://unionbindingcompany.com/ to practice my skills in css, i tried adding some bootstrap but i ended up in a mess of presents and blah, blah, blah.
so how can i make something like that? sorry if its a lot to explain or maybe is simple, but i can make it just giving it a modify to the bootstrap navbar?
i tried giving it a diferent flex to the container of the dropdown bar but don't show any good results.

```css
/* body and root stuff */
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0.813rem;
  font-family: "Assistant", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: white;
}
/* img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
} */
header {
  text-align: center;
  background: rgb(255, 123, 0);
  color: white;
  padding: 2em auto;
}
/* body and root stuff end */
/* nav bar and header stuff */
.nav-bar-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
#union-logo-container {
  padding-top: 0px;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  border-right-width: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  width: 10%;
}

.union-logo-nav {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.#navbarDropdownMenuLink {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
 <div class="nav-bar-container">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light" id="union-logo-container">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img
              src="/union project/img/logo navbar.jpg"
              width="30"
              height="30"
              alt=""
              loading="lazy"
              class="union-logo-nav"
            />
          </a>
        </nav>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
          <button
            class="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
            aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation"
          >
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a
                  class="nav-link dropdown-toggle"
                  href="#"
                  id="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                  role="button"
                  data-toggle="dropdown"
                  aria-haspopup="true"
                  aria-expanded="false"
                >
                  Dropdown link
                </a>
                <div
                  class="dropdown-menu"
                  aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"
                >
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just use the css transform with rotate.  be sure to set width

```css
a{
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  display:block;
  width:1em;
   }
```

```html
<a href='#'>Action</a>
```